# Regarding homology of fiber bundle

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, differential-topology, cohomology

Let $f: X\to Y$ be a smooth map between smooth manifolds, both connected. Let $Y=\cup_{i=1}^k Y_i$ be a finite union of disjoint locally closed submanifold $Y_i$ such that $f^{-1}(Y_i)\to Y_i$ is smooth fibre bundle for $i=1,2, \cdots, k$ and the induced map $f_*:H_*(f^{-1}(Y_i);\mathbb{Z})\to H_*(Y_i;\mathbb{Z})$ is an isomorphism for all $i$. Then $f_*:H_*(X;\mathbb{Z})\to H_*(Y;\mathbb{Z})$ is also isomorhphism.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you reduce it to the case that $n=2$?

Comment: Yes proof when $Y=Y_1\cup Y_2$ will be very helpful. Can you give some idea ?@kiran

Comment: I am confused but if Y is connected how it can be written as a finite union of disjoint submanifolds?  Do you allow manifolds to have boundaries?

Comment: Y is disjoint union of locally closed submanifolds. If you are not comfortable you can take $Y_i$ to be locally closed set only.

Comment: @tota Maybe apply a tubular-neighborhood theorem to turn Y_1 and Y_2 into an open cover, then try to apply mayer vietoris?

Comment: The problem is that we don't know over tubular neighbourhoods f is fibre bundle or not@kiran.